# Error on production with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
git://github.com/plataformatec/devise (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
```

I see this when i move my site on production. On my localhost it works fine .. whats going on with this devise?

my gem file:

```
gem 'devise',              git: 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise'
```

and im using rails 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is run bundle install --deployment. What's happening is that your gems are being installed to the $HOME, and passenger is running as the nobody user, who has a different $HOME. Running --deployment installs the gems local to the application, so Passenger will find it.

This is answer from github and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this on production because apparently your production environment does not have the `devise` gem installed. If you are using heroku, make sure the gem is in the proper gem scope (not `:development`, `:test`)  so that when the `precompiler` runs, it is installed. If you are using another environment, you should do exactly what the error says and bundle install it, so that the gem is installed to the production environment.

Comment: i use bundle install --without development test and it say : Using devise (3.1.0.rc2) from git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git (at master)

Comment: im using passenger with nginx

Comment: try precompiling on your local system and pushing to prod, and see if that does anything.

Answer (score 0):

run `bundle install` locally. Then push again to production.